# Show/Hide All or Toggle Multiple divs With One Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle, show-hide

Forgive me if this topic has been overdone. I've read through lots of posts and haven't quite found what I'm looking for, which is why I'm asking.

**I want to have one checkbox that says "Show All" and when you check it multiple divs show. When you uncheck it, the divs hide**

I was able to show/hide one div with an id using a checkbox, but I'm not sure how to use a class element so I don't have to write out every div id. This is the code I was using:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Show All
<div id="links"><a href="#">Link Title</a></div>
```

AND

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#link').hide();


    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
        //  ^
           $('#links').fadeOut('slow');
        else 
            $('#links').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

How do I approach this with the javascript so I can show multiple divs on one checkbox click? Maybe with a class like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Show All
<div class="links"><a href="#">Link Title</a></div>
<div class="links"><a href="#">Link Title</a></div>
<div class="links"><a href="#">Link Title</a></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You reference all elements with a certain class like this: `$(".links")` - then you can call `.fadeOut()` etc just like when you use an "id" value. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` for `class` and `#` for `id`.

```
$('.link').hide();
$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
    //  ^
       $('.links').fadeOut('slow');
    else 
        $('.links').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: This is correct. For some reason I tried it before I posted the questions and it didn't work (think I forgot to clear my cache), but it's working perfectly now. Thank you sir!